# How to Modify browser added Headers and Footer when printing using browser

Tags: javascript, firefox

I wish to know if it is possible (in any browser) to modify the browser added headers and footers when printing. I know you can prevent then from appearing by adjusting @page margins. But I wish to be able to change the text of the headers and footers.

And most importantly be able to pass a string from Javascript of similar web based technology to the browser (or to an extension of the browser) which would adjust the values of the header and footer.

I m aware that firefox allows custom text to be added as header and footer, but if there an extension to pass the string using JS or similar.

Comment: Hey, this seems like a question you could find an answer for on google! Please try to find the answer and if you are unsuccessful come back and ask then. Include anything you have tried and has worked / not worked! Thanks!

Comment: I did the searching before posting the question. I also did try to see if it is possible for the browsers I had been using. But only Firefox browser offered most modification to the headers and footers. However the modifications had to be brought manually. and cannot be done automatically using javascript or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`print` media style sheets](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-print/). Put all rules you want to be applied for the print profile in a wrap like:

```
@media print {
   .header, .footer {
       display:none;
   }
}
```

Snippet

```css
body {
  font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.header, .footer {
   display:table;
   width:100%;
   background:#333;
   color:#fff;
   text-align:center;
   text-transform:uppercase;
   padding:10px;
}
.main {
   padding:10px;
   min-height:100px;
}

@media print {
   .header, .footer {
      display:none;
   }
}
```

```html
<header class="header">Header</header>
<main class="main">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sed ornare sapien. Proin non pulvinar purus. Suspendisse non nulla eu est viverra dapibus at nec turpis. Maecenas vel ultrices massa. Vestibulum mauris felis, aliquam in tincidunt vel, laoreet eu arcu. Cras commodo non metus a scelerisque. Praesent rutrum at ipsum at mollis. Nullam interdum nulla ex, id malesuada nisl eleifend eget. Donec enim justo, sollicitudin quis varius sit amet, consequat in nisl.</p>
</main>
<footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
```

Comment: I want to modify the headers that the browser adds. Not to add my own headers to the page.

Comment: @MohamedJailam, most browsers like Chrome offer an option to add/remove the headers. You can change the header text by updating the title of the page before printing using JavaScript. The footer is not possible since it gets the current URL of the page.